# jquery checkbox if cheked raise all id values

Tags: jquery, checkbox, sum

i get some question how to make if checkbox with id='paysms' is cheked , raise all element's sum with id='value' , else default value.

here is the code.

```
<table class='table'>
<tr>
<th width='80%'>some things</th>
<th width='20%'>price (usd)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='80%'>thing1</td>
<td width='20%' id='value'>1.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='80%'>thing2</td>
<td width='20%' id='value'>2.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='80%'>thing3</td>
<td width='20%' id='value'>3.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='80%'>thing4</td>
<td width='20%' id='value'>15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='80%' style='border: none; background: none;'></td>
<td width='20%'><label><input id='paysms' type='checkbox'> sms</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please show us.

Comment: An `id` is supposed to be unique. Try using `class` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

undefined's answer doesn't seem to do exactly what you wanted (from what I understand).  I think you get the point by now that IDs must be unique, so heres the javascript:

```
$('#paysms').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".value").each(function() {
            $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html()) + 1 + ".00");
        });
    } else {
        $(".value").each(function() {
            $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html()) - 1 + ".00");
        });
    }
});​
```

and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EwEZK/3/

It would need modification if you wanted to have decimal values other than .00, however.

Comment: where i need to place that jquery code at begining html or after , and need document ready function?

Comment: @user1608442 Document ready is required if you put it in the head, which is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be *unique*, you should use classes instead, try the following:

```
<table class='table'>
<tr>
<th width='80%'>some things</th>
<th width='20%'>price (usd)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='80%'>thing1</td>
<td width='20%' class='value'>1.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='80%'>thing2</td>
<td width='20%' class='value'>2.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='80%'>thing3</td>
<td width='20%' class='value'>3.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='80%'>thing4</td>
<td width='20%' class='value'>15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='80%' style='border: none; background: none;'></td>
<td width='20%'><label><input id='paysms' type='checkbox'> sms</label></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p id='result'><p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#paysms').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var vals = 0;
        $('.value').each(function() {
            vals += parseInt($(this).text(), 10)
        })
        $('#result').text(vals) 
    } else {
        $('#result').text("")
    }
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fggE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `id='value'` to `class='value'`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var price = 0; //default value
    $('#paysms').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('.value').each(function(){
               price += parseFloat($(this).html());
            });
        } else {
            price = 0; // back to default
        }
    });
});
```